# Magic Mouse Battery Status in MenuBar

Tags: xcode, battery, batterylevel, magic-mouse

I'm new to mac and everything around, I just want to know if I can code a sort of plug-in to show the batterie of the magic mouse, in the menu bar.

What is the type of template i have to choose in Xcode to realize my idea.

Comment: Actually the battery status is displayed in the built-in Bluetooth menu bar item. If you want a custom menu bar item, create a standard Cocoa application, implement `NSSStatusItem` and make the application faceless. To get the value of the battery you have to parse IORegistry.

Comment: Thanks men for the awnser :)

Answer (score 1):

So this answer is more a shell-first answer, but you can execute shell commands in ObjectiveC/Swift too.

You can get the percentage of your bluetooth devices pretty easy with this shell command:

```
ioreg -l | grep BatteryPercent
```

With a little bit of regex you should be able to get the number:

Regex 1: https://regexr.com/3ouu3
Regex 2: https://regexr.com/3ouu6

Or as a complete shell solution:

```
ioreg -c BNBMouseDevice |grep '"BatteryPercent" =' | tr -dc '0-9'
```

And the same for the Magic Keyboard:

```
ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard |grep '"BatteryPercent" =' | tr -dc '0-9'
```

Answer (score 0):

So know I have differents informations I would like to know to insert the BatteryPercent from the IORegistery explorator in my code ;)

I have the Bundle Identifier from IORegistery :com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch